# MySQL the whole query fails if result of sub query is NULL

Tags: php, mysql, sql, select, subquery

I have a situation where I need to generate rows with random data out of the same table's valid data

I have generated ID by php `rand($min, $max)` function with `$min = 1` and `$max = [SELECT MAX(ID) FROM patient] - 1`

```
Select

tblFirstName.FirstName,
tblLastName.LastName,
tblBirthDate.BirthDate,
tblLocation.Location

From

(SELECT FirstName FROM patient WHERE ID > 11445 AND FirstName != '' LIMIT 1) AS tblFirstName,
(SELECT LastName FROM patient WHERE ID > 74964 AND LastName != '' LIMIT 1) AS tblLastName,
(SELECT BirthDate FROM patient WHERE ID > 26360 LIMIT 1) AS tblBirthDate,
(SELECT Location FROM patient WHERE ID > 68356 AND Location != '' LIMIT 1) AS tblLocation
```

Now in the `ID > 26360` from the above query 26360 is that random number and `>` is used to avoid the possibility if 26360 was deleted

**PROBLEM:**

if any of the sub query returns no result complete query fails and return nothing.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try this:

```
SELECT (SELECT FirstName FROM patient WHERE ID > 11445 AND FirstName != '' LIMIT 1) AS tblFirstName,
         (SELECT LastName FROM patient WHERE ID > 74964 AND LastName != '' LIMIT 1) AS tblLastName,
         (SELECT BirthDate FROM patient WHERE ID > 26360 LIMIT 1) AS tblBirthDate,
         (SELECT Location FROM patient WHERE ID > 68356 AND Location != '' LIMIT 1) AS tblLocation
```

Answer (score 4):

Change all your queries to :

```
SELECT FirstName FROM patient WHERE ID > 11445 AND FirstName != '' UNION SELECT NULL FROM DUAL LIMIT 1
```

i.e. add UNION SELECT NULL FROM DUAL (in all your subqueries)

Answer (score 0):

You need to use LEFT OUTER JOIN:

```
Select

tblFirstName.FirstName,
tblLastName.LastName,
tblBirthDate.BirthDate,
tblLocation.Location

From

(SELECT FirstName FROM patient WHERE ID > 11445 AND FirstName != '' LIMIT 1) AS tblFirstName
LEFT JOIN
(
(SELECT LastName FROM patient WHERE ID > 74964 AND LastName != '' LIMIT 1) AS tblLastName, (SELECT BirthDate FROM patient WHERE ID > 26360 LIMIT 1) AS tblBirthDate,
(SELECT Location FROM patient WHERE ID > 68356 AND Location != '' LIMIT 1) AS tblLocation
)
```